# User with Highest Profile View

Tags: discussion

Is there any way we can calculate user with highest profile view from complete SO network?

AFAIK I think Jon Skeet would be the only guy with highest profile views.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From Stack Overflow? Sure - just [use the data explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/231226):

```
select top 10 Id as [User Link], Views 
from Users
order by Views desc


User Link       Views  
--------------- ------ 
Jon Skeet       843188 
Eric Lippert    231196 
BalusC          168140 
Marc Gravell    162640 
Jeff Atwood     158759 
Darin Dimitrov  136805 
Hans Passant    123060 
CommonsWare     105625 
Bill the Lizard 103947 
casperOne       79249
```

Comment: I made that list?  That's...  Surprizing...

Comment: You're... Notorious ;-)